# Need a function for a dynamic table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm learning about functions. I've explored a couple tutorials, but I can't yet visualize how my immediate problem can be translated into a function. In addition, I got an error message when I put a sample function inside a while loop; something about not being able to redeclare it.

So I wondered if anyone could show me how you would convert the following to a function. Note that all the code, including the table cell, is inside a while loop. Would I have to somehow remove it from the while loop before I could put a function in it?

```
switch($Latin)
{
 case 'Aix sponsa':
 case 'Gavia immer':
 $star_rating = '<sup><span style="color: #f00;"><b>+</b></span></sup>';
 break;
 default:
 break;
}

<td class="Symbol"><a href="$GZ_URL/life/'.$LatinL.'" title="'.$Symbol.'  ('.$Latin.')">'.$row['Symbol'].'</a>'.$star_rating.''.$DesigAst.'</td>
```

Comment: Define the function outside the loop. Then **call** it inside the loop, passing the iteration variable as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the function outside the loop:

```
function get_star_rating($Latin) {
    $star_rating = '';
    switch ($Latin) {
        ...
    }
    return $star_rating;
}
```

Inside the loop, do:

```
echo <td class="Symbol"><a href="$GZ_URL/life/'.$LatinL.'" title="'.$Symbol.'  ('.$Latin.')">'.$row['Symbol'].'</a>'.get_star_rating($Latin).$DesigAst.'</td>
```

Comment: It isn't actually working for me, but that's probably because $Latin itself is defined inside the while loop. So if I put this BEFORE the while loop, then $Latin has no value. However, your example helps me understand how to translate my code into a function. I'll just have to play around with it until I find a workaround.

Comment: `$Latin` gets its value from the function argument. I think you need to brush up on the basics of computer programming -- if you don't understand functions, you won't get far.